# Which Element property is connected to the CSS `:checked` selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm using the CSS `:checked` selector, like

```
.myCheckbox:checked {
    // style checked state
}
```

But, when I set

```
$('.myCheckbox').each(function() { this.checked = false });
```

the above CSS remains matched.

How can I get the above `:checked` CSS rule to stop matching?

Comment: You might also want to check browser support for ```:checked``` pseudo selector.

Comment: Why don't you use addClass and removeClass for the elements that are checked or not? On the .each function make if(checked == "true"){$(this).addClass('yourClass')} . Just a friendly suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works absolutely fine for me: http://jsbin.com/xakugemi/1/edit?html,css,output. Just check the checkbox and then click the `uncheck` button. However notice the missing browser support for the `:checked` selector in IE<8.: http://caniuse.com/#search=checked.

Comment: Same for `<html><head><style>.myCheckbox:checked {margin-left: 50px;}</style><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script></head><body><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox" checked=""></body></html>` (type in the jQuery line of code given in question into JavaScript console to view change)

Comment: Yeah of course. I also made a bin/fiddle, just after I posted and verified the same. In my actual code I was just selecting the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

In your code use: `$(this).prop('checked', false);` to check/uncheck a checkbox element.

Comment: Which is just a slower version of `this.checked = false` (what OP tried).

Comment: Agreed. In that case, $.each should be substituted with the faster for loop as well ;)

Comment: @Oriol: Not much slower, but definitely cleaner. However, being functionally equivalent, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Bergi .. I remembered later it's equivalent. My bad.